# Returning large array from Google Script is slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From a script on a google spreadsheet, I have a function that returns a 'large' matrix (8 col x 40320 rows). This function is called at 4 different places in the same spreadsheet.

When I change an input for the function, the refresh is very slow (I have a 'Loading...' text displayed in the cells for a couple of minutes). The script by itself is very fast, it finishes in less than 1s when I am running it in debug mode.

Is there something I can improve to make the refresh faster?

Below is the culprit function simplified. When I am calling test() in debug, it takes < 1s. When I am calling generateLargeArray($A$1) in the spreadsheet , it takes around 1mn for a call by 2 cells, 4 mn for a call by 5 cells.

```
function test()//execute in < 1s
{
     var data = generateLargeArray(42);
}

function generateLargeArray(inputToTriggerComputation) {
     var largeArray = [];
     for(var l = 0; l < 40320; l++)//40320
     {   
         var currentLine = [];
         for(var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
         {   
         currentLine.push(c+inputToTriggerComputation);
         }
         largeArray.push(currentLine);
     }

     return largeArray;
}
```

Comment: share the function please

Comment: Does the loading finish immediately if you insert or delete a row above the cell?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk code added

Comment: @idfurw I am not sure to understand what you want. Are you saying to try to add a row above the cell when the function si recalculation ? If so, it is not easy because the sheet is not responsive. (and rather not convenient if I need to do it everytime).

Comment: Yes, just want to see if it is relevant to the problem.

Comment: @idfurw no impact unfortunately. What is the idea behind that you thought could help ?

Comment: I wondered if it relates to recalculation but it seems not.

Comment: Look at Best Practices in Support in the documentation.  I would try to the the data all  at one time with getValues() into one two dimensional array.  My experience suggest a 10x improvement in performance as opposed to doing it one line at a time.  It's hard to offer any more advice than that since you have no defined your subfunctions

Comment: @Cooper let's say that the sub function is the same as the snipped. I don't see any need for the getValues(), the setValues() would help but I receive an error when doing so (Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues)

Comment: Well if you don't see any need for getValues() then I guess you don't need my help.

Comment: @Cooper thanks for point out the getValues() that lead me to the setValues() that looks like similar to the getValues() but for write (this is what I need: write a matrix in the spreasheet).  However, the setValues() throws an exception and I did not find yet the way to work around it.

Comment: If you don't have access to the spreadsheet then I can't help you.  But just wondering are you logged into more than one account at the same time.  That has been a problem in the past and it could be your problem.  Try using two different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is not much you can do. The performance is hit by data being sent to update the sheet, not by computation itself.
Check the code below (I added console logs) and observe the execution time:

[image]

```
function test(){
    console.time('test')
     var data = generateLargeArray(Math.random());
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)
     console.timeEnd('test')
}

function generateLargeArray(inputToTriggerComputation) {
      console.time('generateLargeArray')
     var largeArray = [];
     for(var l = 0; l < 40320; l++)//40320
     {   
         var currentLine = [];
         for(var c = 0; c < 8; c++)
         {   
         currentLine.push(c+inputToTriggerComputation);
         }
         largeArray.push(currentLine);
     }

    console.timeEnd('generateLargeArray')
    return largeArray;
}
```